# Empty space isn't all that empty - or is it? &nbsp;, ordinary space or what?

Tags: unicode, character-encoding, special-characters, html-entities

I have a really strange problem. I want to load some text and an image from an RSS feed (not my own), so that's what I do. I display the image floating right and the text floating left. This usually looks good, but not in this case:

(RSS feed and my page are both UTF-8)

[image]

The text wraps under the image, even though there's lots of room for it. What's going on? I view the source, and it looks like this:

```
Elektronisk affald er en kæmpe klimasynder, ...
```

So that looks peaceful enough, but look what happens if I press F12 to open the developer tools:

[image]

There's non-breakable spaces in there! But I don't see them in source view, so they're not HTML entities, but actually coded into the text! Time for some hex view - I take the oritinal text and paste it into Sublime Text:

```
00000000:  456c 656b 7472 6f6e 6973 6b20 6166 6661 6c64 2065 7220 656e  :Elektronisk affald er en
00000018:  206b c3a6 6d70 6520 6b6c 696d 6173 796e 6465 722c 2066       : k..mpe klimasynder, f
```

Both spaces show up as "20", which in my book is a perfectly normal space. What's going on here?

Time for some PHP replace:

```
str_replace( chr(160) , chr(32) , $mystring );
```

should convert these nbsp's to spaces:

[image]

Well, the non-breakable spaces are gone, and new "breakable" spaces have been introduced, but so has something else! What is it? Back to the hex viewer:

```
00000000:  456c 656b 7472 6f6e 6973 6bef bfbd 2061 6666 616c 64ef bfbd  :Elektronisk... affald...
00000018:  2065 7220 656e 206b c3a6 6d70 65                             : er en k..mpe
```

So each non-breakable space (which originally registered as 0x20 in the hex viewer) has now been replaced with EF BF BD 20.

Ok, this is where I give up. What the devil is going on here!?

Comment: [EFBFBD is likely UTF-8 for REPLACEMENT CHARACTER](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specials_(Unicode_block)) and no, I don’t know where it comes from. Perhaps the original file is not being read as UTF-8 (or appropriate)?

Comment: Hypothesis: PHP is treating the string in `str_replace` (and elsewhere?) as ASCII characters/bytes, not Unicode.

Comment: Bingo! I downloaded the file directly to my disk and hex-viewed it, and it was a 0xC2 0xA0 UTF-8 non-breaking space, so by just replacing the A0, that left the uninterpretable 0xC2. By using `str_replace( chr(194).chr(160) , chr(32) , $mystring );` I get what I was looking for. Thanks!